# Makefile dependency cannot execute sequentially

Tags: makefile

This is my Makefile script. I want it to run step-by-step. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to run my Makefile, however, the steps are running together, which violates the dependency. How to overcome this dependency issue?

```
all: step3

step1:
    python3 script1.py

step2: step1
    python3 script2.py

step3: step2
    python3 script3.py
```

In this Makefile, step3 is not executed lastly, but instead, it is executed together with step1, is there a solution for this?

Comment: How did you determine that they run at the same time?

Comment: script3.py will draw a graph based on the data extraction from script 1 and script 2, when I run the Makefile, the graph is plotted at the same time as the data extraction, and the graph is wrong due to incomplete data extraction.

Comment: Is this the exact makefile you use? Can you reproduce the problem if you replace the python calls with something like `sleep 10` (and count the number of seconds it ends up sleeping in the end).

Comment: As written, the makefile should always run and complete `script1.py` before starting `script3.py`   It's possible that your `script1.py` launches a subtask in the background, and that doesn't complete before `script3.py` is invoked?   To debug the behavior, add the lines `@echo running $@` and `@echo done $@` to the beginning and end of each of your target recipes.  You can also add a `sleep 1` there as @HolyBlackCat suggested to make any timing issues more prominent.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "using Visual Studio to run my makefile"; Visual Studio doesn't have an instance of normal make provided with it.  I think it does provide a version of `nmake` which is a totally different thing although the syntax is similar.  If you open a terminal and run `make` from within the directory containing your makefile do you see the same behavior?